# SSE2 - "The system cannot execute the specified program"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, assembly, visual-c++-2005, sse2

I recently developed a Visual C++ console application which uses inline SSE2 instructions. It works fine on my computer, but when I tried it on another, it returns the following error:

**The system cannot execute the specified program**

Note that the program worked on the other computer before introducing the SSE2 code.

Any suggestions?

PS: It works when I compile the code on the other computer and run it. I think it has something to do with the manifest from what I've scrounged off the net.

Comment: The other computer probably just doesn't support the SSE2 instruction set.

Comment: Er... So how did the research of the obvious guess turn up? I mean the one about problematic computer's CPU not supporting SSE2 instructions?

Comment: It supports SSE2 instructions

Comment: @Jacob Are you 100% certain of this? What kind of processor is in the other computer.

Comment: 100% sure - it works when I compile the code on the other computer and run it. I think it has something to do with the manifest from what I've scrounged off the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the use of the SSE2 instructions is requiring a DLL which isn't present on the second system.

Here's a blog entry on how to figure out exactly which one:
[How to Debug 'The System cannot Execute the specified program' message](http://blogs.msdn.com/nikolad/articles/427101.aspx)

Comment: I don't think it requires a DLL - I already tried  the Dependency Walker.

Comment: @Jacob - Did you look in the event log to see if there's a message about the failure?

Comment: @Jacob - I think Aaron means the Windows event log:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427

Answer (score 0):

If you've built a debug version , a Release build might work on the other machine.

If not, you need to figure out which Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable your program requires and install it on the other machine.

Comment: It was the release version - I installed the redistributable with one of the codes I saw in the manifest - perhaps, I should look for the redist with the other - thanks!